# Why does the id number of a deleted record gets skipped, when new record is added to the database (MySQL/Knex)?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I am learning knex, express js and MySQL and came across an issue I cannot figure out.

What I mean is, I have, say, 5 records in my database, with IDs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

After I delete the record with ID number 5, and add a new one in its place, the new record gets the ID number 6, instead of 5. When I delete that new record too, and add a new one, it will be 7, and so on...  I believe that there is not really a problem, it is that I don't fully understand how indexing works...

Help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: That's because the Id has [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 1):

The Auto index uses a sequence internally which gets selected as the value. You can read up on SQL sequences they are not very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the only case where `AUTO_INCREMENT` ids are "burned".

InnoDB grabs the next id when it needs it, but it may later decide to `ROLLBACK` or that a `UNIQUE` constraint is violated, etc.  Or, as you are doing, `DELETE` the row later.

All this is for making `AUTO_INCREMENTs` efficient.  Do *not* assume anything about them other than that they are unique.

"How indexing works" -- Think of a list of people in a club or company or city, and one of them leaves or dies or whatever.  That slot is lost.